# Why do I still see my manually-deleted photos in Photos in OS X El Capitan

Tags: photos, macos, photos.app

So the question is really simple. I am using Photos app on my mac, without the knickknacks like Photo Stream, iCloud etc. The exact location of photos is the default one: /users/xxx/Pictures/Photos Library/Masters.

I have deleted some photos directly from the Masters folder in Finder, then also from the trash. Yet I still see these photos in Photos app. When I go to Finder again the photos are not there anymore. How come are these photos still displayed in Photos? Are they cached somewhere? Even a restart still shows me those.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem.  Not only were the pictures still being displayed within the Photos app, the pictures (and their folders) that I have deleted manually in the Masters folder, have reappeared in that folder again after when I clicked on a few images within the Photos app.  The best way apparently to permanently delete the pictures would be to do so within the Photos app (see http://www.imore.com/how-delete-images-and-videos-photos-os-x#delete-permanent).